# shiro redirect by role on authentication webapp

Tags: java, security, authentication, jax-rs, shiro

We are Writing JAVA WebApp with JAX-RS(Jersey) using Shiro as Sequrity.

We have:

- 3 different roles each has own home page
- Single login page for all users

When user logs in, **How to redirect user to his own home page according to his role** after authentication.

Some code from shiro ini:

```
authc.loginUrl = /login.html

[urls]
/apps/admin/** = authc, roles["admin"]
/apps/teacher/** = authc, roles[teacher]
/apps/student/** = authc, roles[student]
```

**Ex:**

1. Someone tried to access our webapp, and he will be redirected to *login.html*
2. After entering username/password he will redirected to his own homepage accordign to role

   - */apps/admin/home.html* if he has *admin* role
   - */apps/teacher/home.html* if he has *teacher* role
   - */apps/student/home.html* if he has *student* role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same requirement i did following way.....

```
 if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {  
      if (currentUser.hasRole("admin")) {
          response.sendRedirect("app/admin/adminpage.jsp");
      }
      else if (currentUser.hasRole("student") || currentUser.hasRole("admin")) {           
         response.sendRedirect("app/student/studentpage.jsp");         
      }
     else if (currentUser.hasRole("teacher") || currentUser.hasRole("admin")) {      
         response.sendRedirect("app/teacher/teacherpage.jsp");
     }
  } 
 else {
         response.sendRedirect("app/login.jsp");
   }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I did the same way, except I used response.otherUrl ). And I edited your answer for SAO aproach too, if its wrong please correct me.